# Computed property being observed doesn't fire if changed twice in a row

Tags: ember.js

I have an Ember.Object that I'm updating with a property like below, but if I change primaryDemo twice in a row, it doesn't fire, yet if I change primaryDemo, then Rate, it does change. I'm puzzled as to why this is and how I can fix it.

```
dependantChanged: function() {
    console.log('Firing change');
    this.get('_update')(this);
}.observes('primaryDemo', 'Rate', 'Totals'),
```

**UPDATE**: So the first answer and fiddle got me thinking as to what the problem was, and it's due to changing a property on an object and not the object itself. I think ember does a hash check to see if there is a difference. In my case I'm already using underscorejs, so I just change the property, then use _.clone(demo) before doing the set. I'd rather not do that, so will wait to see if there is a more elegant solution before closing this.

Comment: Thanks for a great question. You mean changing the property of primaryDemo won't trigger the observe method but only change the entire primaryDemo will trigger the observe method, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to set `primaryDemo` again. In the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/JjbXb/1/) that does nothing. You need to force tell Ember to notify your observer. [See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ud3323/JW6hM/)...

```
var demo = { Imps: 1, Demo: { Id: 2 } }

var obj = Ember.Object.create({
    dependantChanged: function() {
        console.log('Firing change');
    }.observes('primaryDemo', 'Rate', 'Totals'),
});

obj.set('primaryDemo', demo);
demo.Imps = 2;
obj.set('primaryDemo', demo);

// Notify observers on obj#primaryDemo
Ember.notifyObservers(obj, 'primaryDemo');
```

​

Answer (score 1):

Can you give more details? I created a simple JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/JjbXb/ from your description but changing the same property in a row, as you say, works.

Are you sure the value of `primaryDemo` is different in your 2 consecutive calls?

Comment: Sure, I've updated it to repo it, specifically I'm changing a property on the primaryDemo object. So in my case I get the value of primaryDemo, change it's Imps property, then set it. Attached a jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/JjbXb/1/

Comment: I think you should go with Roy Daniels' solution then.

Comment: In that case you're not actually changing the value of the property--it's still the same object. Objects are assigned by reference in JS, so the change in the object has already been reflected in the primaryDemo property. Try observing 'primaryDemo.Imps'.

Comment: Caveats: the observer will fire twice if you observe both an object and its property. Also, the object has to be an Ember object to be observed, natch.